# Set the server port for sending API requests from Angular to NodeJS in development

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express

I have this MEAN Stack application and for the front-end I'm using Angular 6, I created the users rooting and back-end login system and I've tested it using Postman and it works as expected. but when I use the form I always get this error below:

[image]

I know the problem is to change the port from `4200` to `3000` but haven't found the right solution.

here is my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  constructor(
    private _httpClient: HttpClient
  ) { }


  public auth(user) {
    return this._httpClient.post('users/login', user).pipe(map((resp: any) => resp.json()));
  }

}
```

and this is where I use the service:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { UserService } from '../../services/user.service';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-side-menu',
  templateUrl: './side-menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./side-menu.component.scss']
})
export class SideMenuComponent implements OnInit {

  public positionsList: Array<any> = [];
  public selectedOption: string;
  public feedbackMessage: string;

  public email: string;
  public password: string;

  public formNotValid: boolean;

  constructor(
    private _userService: UserService,
    private _router: Router
  ) { 

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public sendLoginForm() {
    if(!this.email || !this.password){
      this.formNotValid = true;
      this.feedbackMessage = "Both fields are required to login!";
      return false;
    }

    const user = {
      email: this.email,
      password: this.password
    }

    this._userService.auth(user).subscribe(resp => {
      if(!resp.success){
        this.feedbackMessage = resp.message;
        return false;
      }
    });
  }

  public getSelectedOption(option) {
    this.selectedOption = "as " + option;
  }


}
```

Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: What port are you running your angular app on? What does it say about the port after you enter ng serve?

Comment: For Node I'm using the 3000 port and 4200 for Angular app, I know it should be the port because on postman I used this:  `localhost:3000/users/login` and it's working, for Angular I use this `this._httpClient.post('users/login', user)`. But on console it shows: `POST http://localhost:4200/users/login 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Yup, setup `ng serve` with proxy - see my answer.

Comment: This is because you have not specified any host and port in your service, so the angular application considers current running host as your default one i.e. localhost:4200. Use this: return this._httpClient.post('http://localhost:3000/users/login', user).pipe(map((resp: any) => resp.json()));

Comment: it gave me: `Failed to load localhost:3000/users/login: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.`

Comment: Check my answer below. It will solve that too.

Comment: maybe there is some UI problem.can u share your html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the full URL in your call like this

```
this._httpClient.post(window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + ':3000/' + 'users/login', user)
```

Ideally, you should have you microservices behind a reverse proxy and route your requests based on URI paths

Comment: This won't work in production unless the server runs on port 3000 in production as well.

Comment: Even in development mode `Failed to load http://localhost:3000/users/login: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: @PeS Yup. I suggested it as a workaround during development but ideally such cases should be taken care of a reverse proxy in Production. Your answer is better BTW for development. :)

Comment: @NajmEddineZAGA You will have to enable CORS on your server running at port 3000. If its an express server, install the cors module with `npm install cors` and then add it as middleware like this `app.use(cors())`. Refer to [this](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) for more information.

Comment: The error is no longer exist, I think it may be worked. I have to fix another response problem and if it did I'll let you know

Comment: @PramodhValavala _I suggested it as a workaround during development but ideally such cases should be taken care of a reverse proxy in Production_ ... well, yeah. Then you have to deal with CORS, proxy setup in production is less secure (you must basically expose node directly to internet) or more complicated... Setting up proxy in development makes that transparent and same experience for both dev and production. But whatever, don't want to argue :) It is up to OP to decide what he wants to deal with....

Answer (score 8):

You must setup proxy in Angular `ng serve` to foward requests to your API. Modify `package.json` to run `ng serve` with parameters:

```
"scripts": {
   .....
   "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json",
   .....
}
```

and create `proxy.config.json` to forward requests to your backend, for example, assuming your backend runs on the same machine and port 3000:

```
{
  "/api/*": {
   "target": "http://localhost:3000",
   "secure": false
  },
  "/__/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3100",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

I believe this can be configured in `angular.json` as well however have never explored that option.

Edit: Here is how to set this up in `angular.json` ([docs](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server)):

Open `angular.json` and find the key `"serve"`; then in the `"options"` below set the path to proxy config file in the `"proxyConfig"` key:

```json
"serve": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
  "configurations": {
     "production": {
        ...
     },
     "development": {
        ...
     }
  },
  "defaultConfiguration": "development",
  "options": {
     "proxyConfig": "proxy.config.json"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are working with different environments you can set up those in environment files

For example your `evironment.dev.ts` would look like this

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  API_REST_URL: 'https://yourDomainName', // can be http://localhost as well
  API_REST_PORT: 3000
};
```

And in your service you would use it like this

```
import { environment } from '/path/to/environment';

@Injectable()
export class MyService{
  apiPort = environment['API_REST_PORT'];
  apiUrl = environment['API_REST_URL'];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  apiCall(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}:${this.apiPort}/endpoint/path`)
      .pipe(map(data => {
        return data;
      }));
  }
}
```

And to serve your app in `dev` environment you can add your command to `scripts object` in `package.json`

```
 "scripts": {
    ...
    "start-dev": "ng serve --configuration=dev",
    "build:dev": "ng build --configuration=dev",
    ...
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try putting the url for the api calls in a variable and then appending it in the http verbs url with the specific route.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
url='http://localhost:3000/'
  constructor(
    private _httpClient: HttpClient
  ) { }


  public auth(user) {
    return this._httpClient.post(this.url+'users/login', user).pipe(map((resp: any) => resp.json()));
  }

}
```

Comment: `Failed to load http://localhost:3000/users/login: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: add cors plugin in your node file.
cors allow cross origin request response.

Comment: in you node application you have to allow request from __http://localhost:4200 origin. solution provided by @Apar Adhikari should be fine.